# Como colocar variables en la cabecera de una tabla?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una tabla, y esta parte de la cabecera de la tabla.

```
{ key: 'horas_cargadas_fecha', label: 'Horas cargada desde:   hasta:  ' },
```

me gustaria agregar estos datos en la cabecera.

```
response.data.fecha_desde
response.data.fecha_hasta
```

Comment: Podrías dar más datos? La funciones con la que agregas datos. Un ejemplo de la tabla en formato final. Ejemplo de `response.data`. Etc.

Comment: Estás usando `datatables.js` o me parece ?

Answer (score 0):

Se agrega de la siguiente manera:

```
{ key: 'horas_cargadas_fecha', label: "Horas Cargadas. Desde: " +response.data.fecha_desde+" Hasta: "+response.data.fecha_hasta },
```